# ImageMagick chaining woes

Tags: imagemagick

I can't figure out how to properly chain commands in ImageMagick

Things that do what I expect in isolation :

Resize and then crop

```
$ convert input.jpg -resize '400x400>' -gravity center -crop 300x400+0+0 +repage output.jpg
```

Apply overlay

```
$ convert -composite input.jpg overlay.png output.jpg
```

Annotate

```
$ convert input.jpg -annotate +55+357 'The text I want' output.jpg
```

I've had limited success in combining these together for instance :

```
$ convert \( input.jpg -resize '400x400>' -gravity center -crop 300x400+0+0 +repage \) mask.png -composite output.jpg
```

Resizes the image and crops it, then applies my overlay. However regardless of what I try I can't then get the annotation to appear.

What I want to do is something like :

```
$ convert \( input.jpg -resize '400x400>' -gravity center -crop 300x400+0+0 +repage \) mask.png -composite \( -annotate +55+357 'The text I want' \) output.jpg
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question :

Adding `-gravity NorthWest` before the annotation solves the problem.

```
$ convert input.jpg -resize '400x400>' -gravity center -crop 300x400+0+0 +repage mask.png -composite -gravity NorthWest -annotate +55+357 'The text I want' output.jpg
```

I believe this effectively resets the 0,0 after the crop / resize so the annotation appears where it is expected to.

Note that you don't need the parenthesis either.

Credit to snibgo on the ImageMagick forum.